# CSS Animation to next page or redirect, no JS

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, css-animations, transition

Currently working on a site attempting to use only CSS for transitions and animations and (ideally) no Javascript.

I'm looking for information related to having a page load (or redirect ) automatically upon the completion of an animation/intro. My goal is to do this without JS. Trying to challenge my own capabilities using just CSS.

**Is what I am trying to do achievable with only CSS?** I'm finding a lot of info on running an animation upon load of a page so I feel like the reverse of that *may* be possible....or not. I may not be searching for the right terms as I'm pretty green still so apologies if this is a duplicate.

(If I have to bite the bullet and include a small amount of JS, I will. that's life)

Comment: I don't think so - there might be wizards out there but redirecting with CSS? No, I don't think that's possible. But it's possible to redirect with *one* line of JS.

Comment: you could just hide the content of the page using an animation and time the content to display after the intro animation

Comment: Think about it - would it make sense for CSS to handle page redirects or refreshes? Obviously, you can do off canvas pages and animate after some period of time. Something like slider -> https://codepen.io/DisColow/pen/GgPzWM

Comment: great options, gonna use variations of both. thanks!

Comment: No JS? How about this one: [HTML Editor](http://htmlpencil.appspot.com/)?